# DRF Custom permissions for 1 view for auth and non auth users

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Idea is non-auth user can only GET(list,retrieve) view. Auth user can GET,POST,PATCH,DELETE.

How can i do it in custom permission?

**my view:**

```
class BookViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = serializers.BookSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Book.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by extending the base class `permissions.BasePermission`

```py
from rest_framework import permissions
class IsAuthorOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True
        return obj.user == request.user
```

and then use that as a permission class `permission_classes  =(IsAuthorOrReadOnly,)`